# Why is my custom Validator not working in parsely.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have the following custom validator in parsely.js:

```
window.Parsley
      .addValidator('multipleOf', {
        requirementType: 'integer',
        validateNumber: function(value, requirement) {
        return 0 === value % requirement;
      },
      messages: {
        en: 'This value should be a multiple of %s',
        fr: 'Cette valeur doit être un multiple de %s'
      }
    });
```

and the following HTML:

```
<form action="" class="group-form" data-parsley-validate>
    <input type="" name="" placeholder="Enter Phone" data-parsely-multiple-of="3" data-parsley-trigger="focusin focusout" >
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Now on `focusin` and `focusout` , i don't really get the error messages , Why ?

if i add the following inbuilt validation check to the input , like so:

```
<input type="" name="" placeholder="Enter Phone"  data-parsley-trigger="focusin focusout" data-parsley-min="10">
```

Now, if i enter a number less than 10 , i get an error message saying the following:

> This value should be greater than or equal to 10.

Why is my custom validator not working in parsely.js ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a typo. It's not "data-pars**el**y-multiple", it's "data-pars**le**y-multiple".